# Difference between ChannelHandler.messageReceived and FrameDecoder.decode in Netty

Tags: java, netty

Both events are fired by Netty framework , with a handle to the ChannelBuffer , and the expectation is that client will process the bytes in the buffer in some manner.

Are there any specific usage/scenarios where one is preferred over the other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should checkout the FrameDecoder javadocs. In short you want to use the FrameDecoder if you need to "buffer" data until a Frame was received. The FrameDecoder will take care of it so other handlers in the pipeline (after it) will only receive a full frame.